# Count the number of occurences of a key in a sorted array recursively

Tags: c++11, recursion, vector

I was trying to solve this problem recursively http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-of-occurrences-in-a-sorted-array/. 
The code I have till now uses a stupid little hack with static variable. Although this works, it would fail if you call the function repeatedly with different keys(as the static variable would still remember the previous set value).

```
int FindCount(const vector< int > &A, int l, int r, int B)
{
    static int count =0;
    // cout<<l<<' '<<r<<endl;
    if(l <= r)
    {
        int mid = (l+r)/2;
        // cout<<mid<<endl;
        if(A[mid] == B)
        {
            count++;
            FindCount(A, l, mid-1, B);
            FindCount(A, mid+1, r, B);
        }
        else if (A[mid] < B)
        {
            FindCount(A, mid+1, r, B);
        }
        else
        {
            FindCount(A, l, mid-1, B);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I can figure out how it should work but have a hard time converting that into code. It should be something like this, once you find the particular key then return 1 and the continue to recusively search the left and right of the key.

Could you help me do this recusively without the use of static variable with a cleaner code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int FindCount(const vector< int > &A, int l, int r, int B)
{
      int count = 0;
      if(l <= r)
      {
          int mid = (l+r)/2;
          if(A[mid] == B)
          {
              count++;
              count += FindCount(A, l, mid-1, B);
              count += FindCount(A, mid+1, r, B);
          }
          else if (A[mid] < B)
          {
              count = FindCount(A, mid+1, r, B);
          }
          else
          {
              count = FindCount(A, l, mid-1, B);
          }
      }
      return count;
 }
```

This should work, although it is still a O(n) algorithm, not very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You yet cast away the return value of all invocations but that at the bottom of the recursion stack (a  stack grows upwards); instead of the `static` `count` you can just add the return value of the recursions to an [automatic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) local variable `count`.

Answer (score 1):

The code contains a serious bug: you should use `size_t` and not `int`. The result could overflow. Indexers and counts should be `size_t` - which is a unsigned 32-bit integer on 32-bit platforms and a unsigned 64-bit integer on 64-bit platforms.

u_seem_surprised has a perfectly valid answer. Another way to solve this problem is to use lambdas and capture the `count` variable:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

size_t FindCount(const std::vector<int> &A, size_t l, size_t r, int B)
{
    using namespace std;
    size_t count = 0;

    function<void(const vector<int>&, size_t, size_t, int)> impl;
    impl = [&count, &impl](const vector<int> &A, size_t l, size_t r, int B)
    {
        if (l <= r)
        {
            auto mid = (l + r) / 2;
            if (A[mid] == B)
            {
                count++;
                impl(A, l, mid - 1, B);
                impl(A, mid + 1, r, B);
            }
            else if (A[mid] < B)
            {
                impl(A, mid + 1, r, B);
            }
            else
            {
                impl(A, l, mid - 1, B);
            }
        }
    };

    impl(A, l, r, B);
    return count;
}
```